# SnapRaid scrub shows tons of data errors on parity drive

Tags: software-raid

I am new to SnapRaid and wonder what is wrong when all scrub runs look like this:

```
...
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242042', diff bits 1048371/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242043', diff bits 1048278/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242044', diff bits 1048591/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242045', diff bits 1047674/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242046', diff bits 1049725/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242047', diff bits 1048050/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242048', diff bits 1048318/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242049', diff bits 1049356/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242050', diff bits 1049158/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242051', diff bits 1047212/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242052', diff bits 1049267/2097152
Data error in parity 'parity' at position '11242053', diff bits 1048615/2097152
...

100% completed, 6380380 MB accessed in 3:49

0 file errors
0 io errors
6084943 data errors
```

Looks like all data on parity is kinda broken. 
But the setup is only 1 month old and scrubbing started just some days ago. 
There are no smart errors or similar and the raid is in sync.
I guess it is related to some misconfiguration or snapraid issue.

Would be great to know how to investigate this problem further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from the guys in the SnapRaid-Forums I could identify the problem: 
It looks like SnapRaid runs into major problems when hitting an I/O error while the first sync is done. From that point all blocks on parity have been jammed.

For everyone hitting this issue here I will provide some info how I could solve it:

Check 100 blocks from offset 11242042 to get the kind of error:

```
$ snapraid -S 11242042 -B 100 check

100% completed, 105 MB accessed in 0:00

100 errors
  0 unrecoverable errors
WARNING! There are errors!
```

Ok, seems like everything is recoverable.

Check how much data is affected:

```
$ snapraid status

[...]
No sync is in progress.
The 100% of the array is not scrubbed.
You have 164 files with zero sub-second timestamp.
Run the 'touch' command to set it to a not zero value.
No rehash is in progress or needed.
DANGER! In the array there are 7926625 errors!

They are from block 7107252 to 15055004, specifically at blocks: 7107252 [...]
```

Ok, to me it was quite a lot... so force a resync from before the first affected block of the parity disk:

```
$ snapraid fix -d parity -S 7000000
```

Alternativly fix already detected bad blocks only:

```
$ snapraid fix -d parity -e
```

If you have mostly everything broken I recommend:

```
$ snapraid --force-full sync
```

It took a couple of hours, but now SnapRaid is happy again.

Comment: Thanks for leaving your solution. Needed this info. 
Too many questions on here where people don't return when they find out an answer